# Is it possible to prefetch an area of Google Maps on a tablet?

Tags: gps, google-maps

Suppose I wanted to download a particular state (of the U.S.) so that I could use GPS while not connected to wireless or 3G/4G on a tablet. Is this possible?
The device I have now is a Samsung T530NU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt downloading a whole state for offline use is gonna happen or allowed (or whether the size is gonna be that minimal) but it is possible to download map for offline reference. See [Download an offline Map](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en) to learn how, from Google.

If downloading a whole state for offline use isn't happening, then you might wanna download all of it, however in smaller chunks/areas, and save them.

Comment: You are correct that the area that can be downloaded isn't very large.